# Wrap an app in another app

Tags: iphone, ios

I was curious as to whether it's possible or not to "wrap" and app inside another. For example, insert the code of YOUR app (hereafter referred to as cookie cutter) into an existing app (hereafter referred to as wrapper) with the wrapper app designer's permission, of course. and have your app sit latent for x amount of time. After x amount of time, the cookie cutter app pulls up and initiates its code. From that point on, the cookie cutter app is accessible by pressing a button in the top left corner of the wrapper app, which will switch views to the cookie cutter. My question comes in two parts.

Part A: is this something that apple would allow? I know there's a certain level of red tape regarding what apple allows and doesn't allow

Part B: Would this be possible, even if Apple allowed it? Would the way that apps are designed allow for this functionality to be part of an app in the first place?

By asking this question, i'm more looking for articles on the subject. It's hard to fit this entire question into a couple words that can be searched for on google. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the app you want to wrap? Do you need the wrapped app to exist as a separate app on the user's home screen? Do you need to share the wrapped app between multiple other apps?

Comment: you could simulate this effect if you had the source code... you can't actually do this though

Comment: In our hypothetical situation, i do have access to the source code for both apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible (I don't know whether it is possible in Jailbroken devices). In iOS each app is sandboxed, so you can't run an app inside an app.

Also running app, terminating it these kind of things are managed by SpringBoard (Simply os). So you can't do this.

---

**Suggestion:**

Why can't you simply display the Second app's icon (in imageView or in button) inside the First app ? When useer tap on that icon open that app using `URLScheme`.

Like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourSecondAppURL]];
```